# How to write a positive function as sum of positive terms only

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation, algebra, factorization

A multivariate polynomial function can be written in a certain form (`x^m (1-x)^n y^k +  ...` ) if the function is Positive in the whole domain and contains a finite set of minimum.

Lets take the following example:

```
fun=a + b + a^2 b + a b^2 - b c + 2 a b c - a^2 b c - 4 a b c d
```

where `0<= a,b,c,d <= 1`.

Now the function `fun` is positive in the whole region spanned by `a,b,c,d` which can be confirmed through `FindMinimum` i.e.,

```
 FindMinimum[{fun, 0<=a<= 1, 0<=b<=1, 0<=c<=1, 0<=d<=1 },{a,b,c,d}]
 {4.07048*10^-7, {a -> 8.09007*10^-8, b -> 0.00543937, c -> 0.99994, d -> 0.500736}}
```

In such scenario, it is guaranteed (at least one way) that `fun` can be organised as `Sum` of terms where each term looks like a `beta integrand` i.e. in the form

fun=$\Sigma k_{i} a^{m1} (1-a)^{n1} b^{m2} (1-b)^{n2} c^{m3} (1-c)^{n3} d^{m4} (1-d)^{n4} $

with $m1,n1,...,m4,n4 >= 0$ and $k_{i} >=0 $ are real numbers .
In this particular case

```
fun=a (1 - b)^2 + b (1 - c) (1 - a)^2 + 4 a b (1 - c) +  4 a b c (1 - d)
```

or  also

```
fun=a (1 - b)^2 + b (1 - c)  + a^2 b (1 - c)  + 2 a b (1 - c) +   4 a b c (1 - d)
```

both are in desired form, where each term is in the form `x^m(1-x)^n` and importantly they are separated with `+`.

**Any strategy how to achieve this?**

Or may any functionality already available that I am not aware of!
There is one functionality `Factor` with `Modulus`. However that does not work on multivariate functions.

NOTE: If the function has minimum for infinitely many points, then it is probably NOT possible to have beta-integrand representation. For example, for the simple case `(a-b)^2` which has minimum(`0`) along the line `a=b`, it is NOT possible to have a representation in terms of beta-integrand.

Comment: Aren't you missing a coefficient in front of $\text{fun}=\sum a^{m1}\dots$?

Comment: @anderstood, yes and edited. This is the important part :) . These $k_{i}$ should be either 0 or positive real numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach, maybe not the most efficient one though.

- use `CoefficientArray` to extract coefficients of your polynomial
- define a polynomial with unknown coefficients in the form you are looking for (beta integrand)
- use `CoefficientArray` on this second polynomial
- identify both; the system is linear, underdetermined, so I used `FindInstance` just to take one solution, but of course that's one among many.

There we go:

```
fun = a + b + a^2 b + a b^2 - b c + 2 a b c - a^2 b c - 4 a b c d;
coefs = Normal@CoefficientArrays[fun, {a, b, c, d}];

obj = Sum[
   If[i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p > 4, 0, 1]*
    alpha[i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p]*a^i (1 - a)^j*b^k*(1 - b)^l*
    c^m*(1 - c)^n*d^o*(1 - d)^p, {i, 0, 2}, {j, 0, 2}, {k, 0, 2}, {l, 
    0, 2}, {m, 0, 2}, {n, 0, 2}, {o, 0, 2}, {p, 0, 2}];
vars = Table[
    If[i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p <= 4, alpha[i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p], 
     Unevaluated[Sequence[]]], {i, 0, 2}, {j, 0, 2}, {k, 0, 2}, {l, 0,
      2}, {m, 0, 2}, {n, 0, 2}, {o, 0, 2}, {p, 0, 2}] // Flatten;

coefs2 = Normal@CoefficientArrays[obj, {a, b, c, d}];
eqs = Thread[(Flatten@coefs - Flatten@coefs2) == 0] // DeleteDuplicates;
eqs = DeleteCases[eqs, True];
ineqs = Thread[vars >= 0];
sol = FindInstance[eqs~Join~ineqs, vars];

fun2 = obj /. sol // First
(* ((1 - a)^2 b (1 - c) + 3 a b (1 - c) + a b^2 (1 - d) + 
   a (1 - b) (1 - c) (1 - d) + a c (1 - d) + 2 a b c (1 - d) + 
   a (1 - b)^2 d + a b (1 - c) d *)

fun - fun2 // Simplify
(* 0 *)
```

You might instead want to transform the linear system into its matrix form with `ArrayCoefficients` and use `LinearSolve`, instead of `FindInstance`:

```
linearsystem = Normal@CoefficientArrays[eqs, vars];
sol = LinearSolve[#2, -#1] & @@ linearsystem;
fun2 /. vars -> sol
(* (1 - a)^2 b (1 - c) + 3 a b (1 - c) + a b^2 (1 - d) + 
    a (1 - b) (1 - c) (1 - d) + a c (1 - d) + 2 a b c (1 - d) + 
    a (1 - b)^2 d + a b (1 - c) d *)

 fun - fun2 /. vars -> sol // Simplify
 (* 0 *)
```

Comment: A question: in principle your `sol` will have all the instances for which the system is solved for this particular form?
One observation: if the expression (to begin with ) has  a constant term say `1 + a b - ...` this leads to two Lists of unequal length for `coefs` and `coefs2`.

Comment: @Boogeyman For the question, `FindInstance` finds a _single_ instance that satisfies the equalities and inequalities, not all of them. Regarding the observation, could you give a complete example of `fun` that fails? I see no problem with `fun = 1 + a*b + b + a^2 b + a b^2 - b c + 2 a b c - a^2 b c -  4 a b c d` for example (i.e. your `fun` plus one). Maybe you tried with a higher order polynomial, in which case you need to adjust the `4`.

Comment: For example, with `fun = 1 + a*b + b + a^2 b + a b^2 - b c + 2 a b c - a^2 b c - 
  4 a b c d^2` (note the square at the end), you get an working solution by changing 4 to 5 (which is the higher order term ($abcd^2$). It would deserve automating.

Comment: yes indeed It was O(5) term. However for the following O(4) term it does not work... (it could not find any solution) `fun=1 + 2 a b + a^2 b^2 - 2 c - 2 a c - 2 a b c - 2 a^2 b c + c^2 +  2 a c^2 + a^2 c^2`

Comment: @Boogeyman Indeed, `FindInstance` finds no solution with the positivity contraint (without, it finds some but with some negative coefficients). I am not sure why since apparently there must be some solutions. Would you have any such solution to help?

Comment: , Now I know why this is not working. Its not the problem of your code. The problem is when I have an expression which does not have a finite number of minimum, for those cases even though the function is positive, it can NOT be written as beta integrand. Lets take the following simple positive function `(a-b)^2` which has infinite set of minimum at `0` for `a=b`. I will edit the question. The previous example is also similar case.

Comment: there is something wrong with last part of your code if I don't want to use `FindInstance`? `fun2 /. vars -> sol` ?

Comment: In particular, `FindInstance` also incorporates the inequalities to restrict the coefficients to non-negative.

Comment: @Boogeyman Indeed, the second part does not enforce the inequalities. Note : you can ask for multiple solutions with `FindInstance` (see the doc, third entry). And thanks for the bounty.

Comment: Welcome :)  It really helped me to understand and  I took more interest in `FindInstance`. Its really useful. However when I was trying an example with more variables its extremely slow and I believe your second option with `LinearSolve` will be much faster only if there is a way to restrict for positivity.

Comment: The issue here is that it is "brute-force". It introduces a lot of zero coefficients. There might be some mathematical tricks. For example _maybe_ taking $x=a$, $x=b$, etc. in the function and its derivative might give some simple relationships. I am not sure however.

Answer (score 1):

I included this code as a friendly version to the excellent code from @anderstood. This script handles the cases with number of variables from 1 to 4. Extension to more variables can be easily done by extending the Switch span.

```
Clear[ExtractFactors]
ExtractFactors[f_, vars_] := Module[{rf, ef},
  rf = CoefficientRules[f, vars];
  ef = Map[First, rf];
  Return[ef]
]

pol = 1 + a b d + b + a^2 b + a b^2 - b c + 2 a b c - a^2 b c - 4 a b c d;
pol = 1 - a^2 b^2 c d^2;
pol = 1 + a b d + b + a^2 b + a b^2 - b c + 2 a b c - a^2 b c - 4 a b c d;
pol = 1 - a b c d;
pol = 1 - a^2 b^2 c^2 d^2;
pol = 1 - a b c;
pol = 1 - a - a^2;
pol = 1 - a b;
pol = a b + a c + c b - a b c;
pol = 1 - a b c d;
pol = 1 - a + a^2;
pol = 1 - a b c d e;
pol = 1 - a b + a^2 b^2;
pol = 1 + a b d + b + a^2 b + a b^2 - b c + 2 a b c - a^2 b c - 4 a b c d^2;

vars = Variables[pol];
monom = ExtractFactors[pol, vars];
numvars = Length[vars];
mexp = Table[Max[Transpose[monom][[All ;; k]]], {k, 1, numvars}];
table = Switch[Length[mexp],
   1, amax = mexp[[1]]; Table[If[i + j > amax || i + j < 2, 0, 1]*a^i (1 - a)^j, {i, 0, amax}, {j, 0, amax}],
   2, amax = mexp[[1]]; bmax = mexp[[2]]; Table[If[i + j > amax || k + l > bmax || i + j + k + l < 2, 0, 1]*a^i (1 - a)^j*b^k*(1 - b)^l, {i, 0, amax}, {j, 0, amax}, {k, 0, bmax}, {l, 0, bmax}],
   3, amax = mexp[[1]]; bmax = mexp[[2]]; cmax = mexp[[3]];Table[If[i + j > amax || k + l > bmax || m + n > cmax || i + j + k + l + m + n < 2, 0, 1]*a^i (1 - a)^j*b^k*(1 - b)^l*c^m*(1 - c)^n, {i, 0, amax}, {j, 0, amax}, {k, 0, bmax}, {l, 0, bmax}, {m, 0, cmax}, {n, 0, cmax}],
   4, amax = mexp[[1]]; bmax = mexp[[2]]; cmax = mexp[[3]]; dmax = mexp[[4]]; Table[If[i + j > amax || k + l > bmax || m + n > cmax || o + p > dmax || i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p < 2, 0, 1]*a^i (1 - a)^j*b^k*(1 - b)^l*c^m*(1 - c)^n*d^o*(1 - d)^p, {i, 0, amax}, {j, 0, amax}, {k, 0, bmax}, {l, 0, bmax}, {m, 0, cmax}, {n, 0, cmax}, {o, 0, dmax}, {p, 0, dmax}], 
   _, Print["Num. of variables should be less than 5"]];
If[Length[mexp] < 5,
   monomials = Union[Flatten[table]];
   np = Length[monomials];
   A = Table[Subscript[\[Alpha], i], {i, 1, np}];
   restrsA = Thread[A >= 0];
   dif = A.monomials - pol;
   coefs = CoefficientRules[dif, vars];
   rels = Map[Last, coefs];
   equs = Thread[rels == 0];
   sol = Quiet@FindInstance[Join[equs, restrsA], A];
   If[Length[sol] > 0,
      polfound = A.monomials /. sol[[1]]; 
      Print[polfound]; 
      Print[Simplify[polfound - pol /. sol[[1]]]], Print["No match found"]
   ]
]
```

Comment: thanks for the implementation. I have also adopted @anderstood method and made it a little nicer. However the cases with more than 5 variables are extremely slow (takes two days for 6-variables and degree-7 polynomial!!). Unfortunately `FindInstance` does not support `Parallelize`. However it is not clear, if I do not put explicit number of instances, whether it looks for all possible instances and then prints the first one!(that would be time-consuming). Btw, `FindInstance` also supports restricting the domain  like `FindInstance[equs,A,NonNegativeRationals]` ... Saves one line ;) .